# Can I customize the intellisense value shown when hovering while debugging in visual studio?

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2008, intellisense

When I hover over a variable in visual studio, it brings up a small control which shows the variable name, type, and a + box for viewing members, etc. But for some types the variable type is replaced by more helpful information such as "{X = 0.0 Y = 0.0 Width = 0.0 Height = 0.0}" for a RectangleF.

Is there a way to specify what should be displayed? Is there an IDE setting? Is there a function attribute?

I am using visual studio 2008, language is visual basic.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The DebuggerDisplay attribute would be what you are looking for:

```
[DebuggerDisplay("x={xvar} Y={yvar} Width = {widthvar} Height = {heightvar}")]
```

More info can be found [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms228992.aspx)

Answer (score 3):

You're looking for [`DebuggerDisplayAttribute`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.debuggerdisplayattribute.aspx). I wrote more info about using it and the capabilities it has [here](http://gregbeech.com/blogs/tech/archive/2008/07/28/tips-amp-tricks-use-debuggerdisplayattribute-for-easier-debugging.aspx).

Comment: *Sorry, that page doesn't exist.*