# Are there attributes in C# for affecting how IntelliSense displays class members?

Tags: c#, attributes, intellisense

Are there any C# attributes that I can apply to class members, to change the way they appear in the IntelliSense listings? This popped into my head when I was building a class with many static constants, and I (briefly!) wanted it to look like an enumeration in IntelliSense.

Yes, that's silly.

But it got me thinking - *is* there any way some crazy programmer can make a class members appear differently in IntelliSense? Make fields look like properties, etc?

For instance, there's the `Obsolete` attribute:

```
[Obsolete("Stop using this. Really. It's old.")]
public int VariableThatIsReallyOld;
```

Which prefixes the word `[obsolete]` to the description of `VariableThatIsReallyOld`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's the DebuggerDisplay attribute described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/471241/can-i-customize-the-intellisense-value-shown-when-hovering-while-debugging-in-vis).

Answer (score 4):

Turns out there also some other attributes at [Custom intellisense for server controls?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/307514/custom-intellisense-for-server-controls) (But the search continues!)

```
[EditorBrowsable(EditorBrowsableState.Never)]
```

Answer (score 3):

I tend to think that manipulating the comments is a much better proposition.

```
///<summary>
/// Bomb!
///</summary>
///<example></example><value></value><![CDATA[]]><param name="ss"></param><exception   cref="ss"></exception><remarks></remarks>
///<returns></returns>
```

If you dig into the options available in the comment structure(which the intellisense and compiler understands) like `<example>,<include>,<see>,<seealso>,<exception>` etc, you can pretty get all the functionality sans performance dip introduced by the attribute.